# would it work like this?

Tags: support, closed-questions

Re closed question [Simplest way to get health insurance for child?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/78544/867), Can I give minimal context, very general, and ask, "Is there a way to file a legal action to have health insurance looked at by the support magistrate, without having to file complete financial data?"

Please keep in mind that Child Health Plus costs $9/month and various family members would happily offer to pay the premiums.

Also can I add: "can an attorney write to the court clerk and ask that question?"

If neither works, suggestions would be gratefully considered.

Answer (score 3):

In general questions that ask "What should I do in these circumstances?" or "which of these options should I take?" are closed as requests for specific legal advice.

Questions about what laws or regulations permit or require are more welcome.

Also, it is unusual for us to get a lawyer or a member o a lawyer's staff asking what to do in a specific case. To put it mildly.

You could certainly ask whether the law permits M to obtain a court order requiring F to file the application for  Child Health Plus, or Medicaid, and what law (if any) permits such an order, and under what conditions.

Much of the detail, particularly in the 4th paragraph of the question is not really relevant and should probably be removed.

Comment: But what I want to know is whether this can be accomplished without submitting full financial statements.  It's massive. / M CANNOT fill out the paperwork for the state's subsidized insurance for children (Child Health Plus).  She lives in another state, and her insurance is employment based.  I have called various government offices and I'm quite certain about this.  Hence "there is no way she can fill out the application in place of F."  I wonder about grandmother?  (NYS resident.)  I think I will call about that idea. Maybe a health navigator will know. / I removed para 4.  Any other sugg.?